# why i can't get one event using laravel and api and postman?

Tags: laravel, api, postman

i want to get event using `laravel` `api` `postman`, i create function `show` in the controller `EventController`, i add `route` but its give me error `404 Not Found`.
and I am sure that event whose `id=70` exist in `db`.

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'EventController@edit');
```

**EventController.php**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);   
       return $event;
    }
```

url : `http://localhost/agendab/public/api/show/70`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an API call to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/agendab/public/api/show/70
```

However, the route you have defined is not configured to match that URL. Update your route to as follows:

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'EventController@show');
```